# mobx extendObservable blocks me from accessing a getter

Tags: javascript, mobx

**How do I add a computed property in a child class?**

This is the code I have:

```
import {
  get,
  makeObservable,
  extendObservable,
  observable,
  computed
} from "mobx";

class Base {
  x = 123;
  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, { x: observable });
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super();
    extendObservable(this, { x2: computed });
  }

  get x2() {
    return this.x * this.x;
  }
}

const child = new Child();
console.log("child.x2=", child.x2);
console.log("get (child.x2)=", get(child, "x2"));
```

The output is:

```
child.x2= ƒ Child@61.x2() {}
get (child.x2)= ƒ Child@61.x2() {}
```

But I **expected to see a number** returned by my getter.
Moving `get x2` to the base class and decorating it with `computed` there works fine, but it doesn't fit my application logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing the docs:

> extendObservable
>
> Can be used to introduce **new properties** on the target object and make them observable immediately. Basically a shorthand for Object.assign(target, properties); makeAutoObservable(target, overrides, options);. However, **existing properties** on target won't be touched.

So I guess you cannot use it for existing property, you either need to remove it from the class and inline pass it directly to `extendObservable` call or use another `makeObservable` call instead.

Comment: yep, read the docs carefully and changed to `makeObservable` in the child class.